# The view didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: django, forms, view, registration

I was following a tutorial trying to create a registration form. Even though the person recording it was able to create a form I wasn't does anybody see any mistakes in my code? The view didn't return an HttpResponse object.

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib import auth
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def registerit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')
        args = {'form3':UserCreationForm()}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        return render_to_response('register.html', args)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please provide a full trace of the error you are getting. That would be helpful is tracing the reason of your error. Just for sake of it Does the url "/accounts/register_success" exists and matches for a view??

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a `HttpResponse` object only if `if request.method == 'POST':`

But if the request method is __not `POST`, you are not returning anything. You probably need to indent the code one level to the left.

```
def registerit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')
    args = {'form3':UserCreationForm()}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('register.html', args)
```

Comment: I dont think the mistake lies there. He must definitely sending a post request.

Comment: I don't think so. The first time the url is accessed it would be a GET request. Not POST.

Comment: Yes he is sending but when he first get to the page he use GET not POST. Thats why this answer is right.